# iOS: Passing object to custom UITableViewCell to UIViewController via a button action on cell

Tags: ios

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`, which have a button on it, IB linked to a function called:

```
- (IBAction)clickUse:(id)sender;
```

In this function, I planned to pass an object from `UITableView`'s data source (an object in a `NSMutableArray`) to next `UIViewController`, when the user clicks the button on the `UITableViewCell`.

I set a property in the custom `UITableViewCell`, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeObject *some_object;
```

In `UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, I pass the object to the cell:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
cell.some_object = [self.cellData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

At this moment I track the object, it's still here. But in the `MyCustomCell` cell, the object is gone and assigned to `nil`. Therefore, the object cannot be passed to next `UIViewController`.

What did I miss?

Comment: where u r handling clickeUse action either in UITableveiwCell or UIviewcontroller?

Comment: in UITableveiwCell. Actually which approach is better?

Comment: yes, u can provide action in viewcontroller. u can get the index from its tag, and also there will no need to maintain array at both places..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's better to use a different approach. You can give each cell button a tag. The tag value could be the row index path.

Your **-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** method could include the following:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
```

And your **-clickUse:** method could look like this:

```
- (IBAction)clickUse:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    SomeObject *object = [self.cellData objectAtIndex:button.tag];

    // do stuff with your object on click
}
```

Comment: with this approach, is it a must for the `clickUse` to be written in UITableView instead of writing it in the custom UITableViewCell class?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a delegate protocol to handle this. Define a delegate on the cell. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, set the `cell.delegate` to the `viewController` that implements that method. Make sure to nil your delegate in your cell's `dealloc` and `prepareForReuse` methods. In my opinion, this is the solution that sets up the cleanest relationships between the objects involved. See example below.

Assigning a button target to an object that is some object other than the superview of the button always seems counterintuitive to me. Or, whenever I work on a codebase where there's a setup like that I find that it eventually gets in the way / confuses things.

Inside CommentCell.h:

```
@class Comment;
@class SMKCommentCell;

@protocol SMKCommentCellDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)commentCellDidTapShowReplies:(SMKCommentCell *)cell;
- (void)commentCellDidTapUsername:(SMKCommentCell *)cell;

@end

@interface SMKCommentCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) Comment *comment;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SMKCommentCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Inside CommentCell.m:

```
#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)didTapShowReplies:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commentCellDidTapShowReplies:)])
    {
        [self.delegate commentCellDidTapShowReplies:self];
    }
}

- (IBAction)didTapUsername:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commentCellDidTapUsername:)])
    {
        [self.delegate commentCellDidTapUsername:self];
    }
}
```

Inside your viewController.m:

```
#pragma mark - SMKCommentCell Delegate

- (void)commentCellDidTapShowReplies:(SMKCommentCell *)cell
{
    // Do something
}

- (void)commentCellDidTapUsername:(SMKCommentCell *)cell
{
    // Do something
}
```

Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
commentCell.comment = comment;
commentCell.delegate = self;
```